# Bootloader keyboard input problem with BIOS calls

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, bios

So I was following with a tutorial on how to make an os and I want to make a program that takes a single char and prints it but it doesn't work.

**Heres the source code**

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov ah, 0
int 0x16
mov al, [test]

mov bx, test
call print

jmp $

print:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    loop:
        cmp [bx], byte 0
        je exit

        mov al, [bx]
        int 0x10
        inc bx
        jmp loop
    exit:
    ret

test:
    db 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: You want `mov [test], al` not `mov al, [test]`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jester pointed out in a comment, you need to store the ASCII output from the BIOS.GetKeyboardKey function 00h in the *test* variable and not the other way round.
Now if you correct this, it's possible and probable that your program will seem to work fine, but we should not cheer too soon! Since you didn't setup the `DS` segment register, it can easily be true that the instruction `mov [test], al` will overwrite some other memory location that you just won't notice unless something crashes...

- You need a correct `DS` to address the variable *test*.
- The BIOS.Teletype function 0Eh that is used in the *print* subroutine expects the DisplayPage argument in `BH` and the (graphics) color in `BL`. You should never use `BX` to point to the message! Use `SI` or `DI` for this.
- Also be aware that your *print* code expects a zero-terminated string, but you don't actually provide that zero!

This is a corrected version of the code:

```
[org 0x7C00]

  xor  ax, ax
  mov  ds, ax

  mov  ah, 00h    ; BIOS.GetKeyboardKey
  int  0x16       ; -> AX
  mov  [test], al ; Store ASCII in zero-terminated string

  mov  di, test
  call print

  jmp  $

print:
  mov  bx, 7     ; BH=0 DisplayPage, BL=7 Color White
.loop:
  mov  al, [di]
  cmp  al, 0
  je   .exit
  mov  ah, 0x0E  ; BIOS.Teletype
  int  0x10
  inc  di
  jmp  .loop
.exit:
  ret

test:
  db 0, 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: To be fair, the `times ... db 0` does happen to put more than one zero byte directly behind the byte reserved for the `test` variable in the question's original code.

Comment: @ecm That's correct, but if one day the code needs a make-over that would bring the `times` count at zero, then the OP's approach would fail. In general it's never a good idea to depend on coincidencies, things that happen to be, but that are not purposely what they need to be.